# Insert an image when the API doesn't have an image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I've scoured the web and couldn't find a way to do this. Maybe I'm overthinking it but I am working on a React project calling on an API. The API (OMDB) displays movie posters but some movies do not have a poster. I have an image in my SRC folder that I want to insert whenever the API doesn't return an image for the movie.

I've tried seeing if the API offered an alternative but they do not. I've tried different ways like an If ElSE statement but it causes an error. Forgive the formatting, first time asking a question here. I'd like to know if there is a way to insert an image or if this is a limitation on the API's side.

EDIT: Included inline ternary expression but IMG is still not coming up on movies with no image. [See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p68eN.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import moviePoster from '../img/moviePoster.jpg';

const MovieList = (props) => {
    const NominateComponent = props.nominateComponent;

    return(
        <>
            {props.moviesList.map((movie, index) => (
                <div className='image-container d-flex justify-content-start m-3'>
                    <div className='d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3 movieImage'>
                        <img src={(movie.Poster !== "N/A") ? movie.Poster : {moviePoster}}  
                        className='moviePoster img-fluid' alt='movie'></img>
                        <div id='overlay'
                            onClick={() => props.handleNominateClick(movie)} 
                            className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>
                            <NominateComponent />
                        </div>
                        <div className='text-left movieTitleText'>
                            <p>({movie.Year}),{movie.Title}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </> 
    );
};

export default MovieList
```

Comment: To clear up your question, are you trying to display only one of the <img> tags depending on whether movie.Poster is equal to 'N/A'? Also, I don't see that if/else statement in your code - is that something you tried but it does not work? What error does it cause?

Comment: @Cirrus86 Yes, sorry let me expand on my question. I included both IMG tags to show what I've attempted. You are right, I am wanting to display an image based on whether the API response comes back with an image or simply N/A. The If Else statement did not work because it was out of scope. I see Payam's response and am trying to get it to work but my image from my SRC folder isn't coming up.

Comment: Try removing the {} around moviePoster in ? movie.Poster : {moviePoster}. You are making it an object.

Comment: @Cirrus86 you are right! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You directly check in inside your src attribute for img, like:

```
<img src={(movie.Poster !== "N/A")?movie.Poster:"default-image-url"}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is what I was trying to figure out but somehow the image I have is not coming up. Am I invoking it wrong?

Comment: You need to replace default-image-url in my code with the (full) url of your default image

Comment: I did, I included {moviePoster} in the edited code snippet. I imported the image from my img folder and named it as moviePoster. Do you suggest using a URL link rather than an image within my folder?

Answer (score 0):

Using @Payam's suggestion worked. Then making sure to not make it an object as @Cirrus86 pointed out did it. Now it's working as intended. Thank you!

```js
 <img src={(movie.Poster !== "N/A") ? movie.Poster : moviePoster }  className='moviePoster img-fluid' alt='movie'></img>
```